# How to use GetFeatureInfo in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I would like to display all features in a feature.

Using GetFeatureInfo how would I write code to display small dots on a WMS layer, which displays pop-up and info when you click on it?

In my attribute table there is only a geometry column, there is no lat and long column. So is it possible to use GetFeatureInfo with this caveat?

I have written the following code:

```
<html>
<head><title>India</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 2000px; height: 800px"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map', 
{
center: [20.5937,78.9629],
zoom:5
});
var usgs = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapper/wms", {
    layers:'mapper:ind_adm1',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "USGS"

}).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this https://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/leaflet/05-WMS-INFO.html link for GetFeatureInfo from the Internet, but am unsure how to use this code in my code properly.

I tried to integrate it, but got a blank window as a result.

Comment: Could we get a picture of the blank result? It is difficult to tell what is going on without it.

Comment: normally the WMS layer draws the little dots (so that needs to be styled on GeoServer) - then you need to look in the browser networking tab to see what is being sent and received from the server for the click,

Comment: The Leaflet core doesn't implement `GetFeatureInfo`. Have you had a look at https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms ?

Comment: Yes I got blank result.

Comment: I don't understand the solution

Comment: When you had the code included​ in your script, what actual http request was generated and sent to the server when you clicked on a point in the map?  Can you edit your question to provide this request.  If you make this same request in a browser do you get any error